# What is the best practice for declaring a global variable in an iOS app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, global-variables

Suppose I have a `UIColor` that I want to use across every view controller to tint it's title/navigation bar. I was wondering what is the best way to declare such a property. Should I declare it as a member of the application delegate? Create a model class for global properties, and declare a static function `+ (UIColor)getTitleColor`? Pass the `UIColor` object to every view controller? Is there another method that I did not describe, that is viewed as being the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this.  I like to do it by putting a category on `UIColor`:

#### UIColor+MyAppColors.h

```
@interface UIColor (MyAppColors)

+ (UIColor *)MyApp_titleBarBackgroundColor;

@end
```

#### UIColor+MyAppColors.m

```
#import "UIColor+MyAppColors.h"

@implementation UIColor (MyAppColors)

+ (UIColor *)MyApp_titleBarBackgroundColor {
    static UIColor *color;
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        color = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.2 saturation:0.6 brightness:0.7 alpha:1];
    });
    return color;
}

@end
```

Then I can use it by importing `UIColor+MyAppColors.h` in any file that needs the title bar background color, and calling it like this:

```
myBar.tintColor = [UIColor MyApp_titleBarBackgroundColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

By what you are trying to do, I think you could do it much easier by using appearance. You can assign different colors to all of your different types of interface elements. Check [the UIAppearance protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for more information.

If this is not what you want, then I would suggest @rob mayoff answer: using a category.